Just some ordinary layers
The answer to this puzzle is a word. What word?



The answer is:

 SHAPES

First work out...

 ...which polygon makes up each layer in this pile of polygons. From top to bottom, they are:
 Square, Heptagon, Triangle, Triangle, Triangle, Triangle, Pentagon, Hexagon, Hexagon, Square.

Now, count up...

 ...the lengths of each run of similar shapes, giving us:
 Square x1, Heptagon x1, Triangle x4, Pentagon x1, Hexagon x2, Square x1.

We now need to...

 ...take the nth letter of each shape name, where n is the length of each run. So we take the 1st letter of [S]QUARE (i.e. S), the 1st of [H]EPTAGON (H), the 4th of TRI[A]NGLE (A), the 1st of [P]ENTAGON (P), the 2nd of H[E]XAGON (E), and the 1st of [S]QUARE (S) again.

 This spells our thematic answer: SHAPES!


Quick and correct, well done!
